# AnyLogic: Agents stopped progressing after certain amount of time

Tags: anylogic

So here is my model, resourcePool links to Process_1 only.

[model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fa7uJ.jpg)

The issue is when I run the simulation, Process_1 stopped processing after a certain amount of time. When it stopped exactly depends on the seed # I used. Below is what it looks like when I ran it for one week. For this particular seed # it stopped on Tuesday morning.

[Simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDoAd.jpg)

And here is the log, you can see it stopped after the 11th agent, even though there is nothing blocking it.

[Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H94qA.jpg)

It does work without problem when I remove the Select Output In/Select Output out. So I believe that has something to do with the issue. Just couldn't figure out why since it does still run for a  bit before everything stuck.

[No issue when removing Select Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOJ3L.png)

I've tried remove the resourcePool link from Process_1 --> No issue.
Remove the Select output block --> No issue.

When uses both together I got this issue.

Comment: how did you setup the SelectOutputs?

Comment: Hi! Select Output In is as default, with both Select Output Outs link to it and have a  probability of 0.5.